# Equivalence between search-LWE and decision-LWE

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

Are there any constraints when it comes to proving that search-LWE and decision-LWE are equivalent? Should we assume that the module $q$ is prime when switching from one version to another?

Please give a good reference where proof exists.